# can't login after generating keytab file

Tags: windows-server-2008, kerberos

I generated a keytab file with the following command:

```
ktpass /out http-web.keytab /mapuser Administrator@my.domain.bar /princ HTTP/localhost:8080@my.domain.bar  /pass *
```

However, now I can't seem to login as the Administrator using the same password I used earlier.

Would generating key tab file in any way change the password??

Answer (score 1):

This question is old, but I recently ran into a similar issue and hopefully this helps someone. According to [this KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/939980), there is a bug in ktpass where using the /pass parameter appends additional characters to the account password.

The article says 2003, but if the last comment [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/dbf2028b-139a-484d-9067-39dd694f2a4b/can-not-logon-account-after-using-ktpass-to-map-a-spn-to-it?forum=winserverDS) is correct then this also affects 2008 and 2008 R2. The comment says that the workaround is to not use /pass, but we used a designated service account instead and that works fine for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE:  I'm not an expert on the key tab stuff, but logically:

You should link your previous question for more info.

Reading this detail and the info from your previous question, it sounds like you were logging in previously with the LOCALCOMPUTER\Administrator account before and your keytab is now for DOMAINNAME\Administrator account.  Two different accounts, with two different passwords.

Answer (score 0):

No, generating a keytab file will not change the password of your user account.

Comment: what a mess. I have no idea why after creating keytab file I can't log back in...